# How do I get the ListTile index in an ExpansionTile?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout, expandablelistview

After expanding the list and then clicking a sub-item, I would like the row that was clicked to change color. At this point, the index all time is 0, which causes all subitems to be highlighted. How to get the correct index so that the clicked row is highlighted only?

**Current state:**

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQjsD.png)

**Vehicle class:**

```
class Vehicle {
  final String title;
  List<String> contents = [];
  final IconData icon;

  Vehicle(this.title, this.contents, this.icon);
}
```

**List of objects:**

```
List<Vehicle> vehicles = [
  Vehicle(
    'Bike',
    ['Vehicle no. 1', 'Vehicle no. 2', 'Vehicle no. 7', 'Vehicle no. 10'],
    Icons.motorcycle,
  ),
  Vehicle(
    'Cars',
    ['Vehicle no. 3', 'Vehicle no. 4', 'Vehicle no. 6'],
    Icons.directions_car,
  ),
];
```

**Widget:**

```
class CreateNewViewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _CreateNewViewPage();
}

class _CreateNewViewPage extends State<CreateNewViewPage> {
  int _selectedIndex;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF000624),
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        title: Text(
          'Example',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Divider(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.4,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 2,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Card(
                    child: ExpansionTile(
                      title: Text(vehicles[index].title, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),),
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Column(
                          children: _buildExpandableContent(vehicles[index], index),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _buildExpandableContent(Vehicle vehicle, index) {
    List<Widget> columnContent = [];

    for (String content in vehicle.contents)
      columnContent.add(
        ListTile(
          title: Text(content, style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),),
          leading: Icon(vehicle.icon),
          tileColor: _selectedIndex == index ? Colors.blue : null,
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              _selectedIndex = index;
            });
          },
        ),
      );

    return columnContent;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update your `_buildExpandableContent` method as shown in the below code:**

```
 List<Widget> _buildExpandableContent(Vehicle vehicle, index) {
        return List.generate(vehicle.contents.length, (index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(
              vehicle.contents[index],
              style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
            ),
            leading: Icon(vehicle.icon),
            tileColor: _selectedIndex == index ? Colors.blue : null,
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                print('Selected Index : $index');// printing selected value to console
                _selectedIndex = index;
              });
            },
          );
        });
      }
```

**CONSOLE OUTPUT:**

```
I/flutter ( 9502): Selected Index : 0
I/flutter ( 9502): Selected Index : 1
I/flutter ( 9502): Selected Index : 2
I/flutter ( 9502): Selected Index : 3
I/flutter ( 9502): Selected Index : 0
I/flutter ( 9502): Selected Index : 1
I/flutter ( 9502): Selected Index : 2
```

**UI OUTPUT :**

[image]

Now you'll get correct index while a `ListTile` inside `ExpansionTile` is tapped.

Answer (score 0):

**An issue occurred based on using the ExpansionTile index for its sub-items as well:**

You are generating the `ExpansionTile` through the listview builder and passed the index to the `_buildExpandableContent` method. So, the index would be same for the all the sub-items of the `ExpansionTile`. So, all the sub items selected in ExpansionTile. You need to get an index from the vehicle.contents. I have tried it by my approach. Modified the `_buildExpandableContent` like below.

```
    _buildExpandableContent(Vehicle vehicle, index) {
    return List.generate(vehicle.contents.length, (index) {
      return ListTile(
        title: Text(
          vehicle.contents[index],
          style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
        ),
        leading: Icon(vehicle.icon),
        tileColor: _selectedIndex == index ? Colors.blue : null,
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            _selectedIndex = index;
          });
        },
      );
    });
  }
```

For your reference, I have attached the picture for your sample below with a runnable state.

[Demo Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8SiX.png)